# integrated weblogic server becoming slow while iterative deployment

Tags: weblogic

i m using jdeveloper 11.1.1.3.when i first run a jspx page the server starts and runs and all works very nicely.then i make some changes in my code and run the jspx page again ,this time the server responds slower than before.the DB insert/updates takes longer time.when i run my page 5th/6th time everything is very slow.To fix this,i had to shut down the server and restart again.

the question is---is there any other way to maintain good speed without restarting server?

thanks to all.

Comment: From my exp, well JDev is slow, so you need RAM, lots of it. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop and delete your app from weblogic  in admin-console host:port/console before each deployment

Answer (score -1):

because weblogic does not delete properly app from memory. Something of app is left in memory if u won't stop and delete manually your app.

hope it helps, best regards.